# Simple Text Formatting in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, uifont

I am trying allow users to copy and paste my text content that sits in a UITextView. I have some title text, which is bold, followed by regular, unbolded text. Any way to set up a UITextView such that a single select-all copy/paste will work on both bold title and non-bold content text?

Currently, I am adding another UITextView and styling it as bold but this requires 2 select/select-all copy/paste operations:

```
txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,60,280,300)];
[txtView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14]];




txtView.text = word.definition;


txtView.editable = NO;
txtView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[txtView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([txtView.text length], 0)];
txtView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
txtView.maximumZoomScale = 10;

UITextView *wordTitle = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 50)];

[wordTitle setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
wordTitle.text = word.term;
wordTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;



[detailsViewController.view addSubview:wordTitle];
[detailsViewController.view addSubview:txtView];

[txtView release]; 
txtView = nil;

[htmlView release];
htmlView = nil;

[scrollView release];
scrollView = nil;


[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
[detailsViewController release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a UIWebView and passing in a HTML string like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //...more code here

    NSString *htmlDefinition = [word.definition stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
                                                                    withString:@"<br />"];

    NSString  *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<h2>%@</h2><p>%@</p>",[word term],htmlDefinition];

   [htmlView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

   scrollView.contentSize = [htmlView bounds].size;

   [scrollView addSubview:htmlView];

   [detailsViewController.view addSubview:htmlView];
   [htmlView release];
   htmlView = nil;


}
```